# Googly analytics count visitors from one page to another

Tags: google-analytics

I have a simple google analytics question which I did not find an answer for.
Lets say I have two pages A and B. I'd like to count unique visits that went from page A to B. That should be somehow covered in the "Content" section but the only related item is "Behavior Flow" which does not answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called "navigation summary" in GA. It's in the content reports, "Content"->"All Pages", then select the navigation summary tab (not in the main navigation, but one of the tabs above the data table). Makes more sense if you drill down to a specific page first.
[image: Navigation summary]